# jenkins Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.local.Cellar.maven.3.6.3.libexec

Tags: maven, jenkins

Jenkins version 2.190.3
Maven Version 3.6.3

Maven_Home : /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec

libexec folder is available at the above mentioned location.

Still not able to run jenkins job. Build jobs finishes with build failure

OS: mac OS High Sierra 10.13

Maven was installed via homebrew

Comment: You should define the location via Global Tool Configuration in Jenkins and not via environment variables...Apart from that you should upgrade your Jenkins version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set MAVEN_HOME to `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/`

Comment: updating as you said gives error as lib folder missing and build gets failed ......